# Limit the number of inboxes loaded in Thunderbird to save memory?

Tags: email, thunderbird, memory-management

I have 3 email accounts I use in Thunderbird, however I only use one of them on a regular basis.

Is it possible to selectively load accounts in Thunderbird to save memory?

Here is the functionality that I'm looking for:

- I want my main account to update as normal
- I want my other accounts to load all messages and update (download mail) **only** when I manually request it to

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean when you start thunderbird you want it to only show you one account?

Comment: @Nima I mean that I don't want to load up all the messages from all the accounts all of the time. (well that was a crap sentence).  I want to load them selectively as needed.

Comment: After reading this reply 3 times I guess my answer to this question is irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah I'll close it.  Thank you for taking a shot at it. :)

Comment: I've made changes to you question to better reflect what I feel you're trying to do.  Feel free to rollback if I'm completely off base.

Comment: @KronoS, your edits make the question completely different than what the subject suggests.

Comment: @psusi is that better?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable "check inbox on startup" and do it manually for the disabled accounts by choosing them and pressing "Get Mail". I doubt it would have a considerable impact on RAM usage though.

**To disable the mail check on startup:**

1. right click on the account
2. Select **Settings**
3. Choose **Server Settings**
4. Disable the option **Check for new messages on startup**

Doing this will tell thunderbird to ignore the disabled email accounts unless you want it to check them.